# Derivative of this integral over square w.r.t. its side length

Tags: integration

Let $f(x,y)$ be continuous function defined on a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$. For $L\in \mathbb{R}_+$, $g(L)$ be the integral of $f$ over the square of side length $2L$ centered on the origin (square inside the domain of $f$),
$$ g(L) = \int_{-L}^L\mathrm  \int_{-L}^{L} f(x,y) \mathrm{d}y d{x}.$$
What is the derivative of $g$ with respect to $L$?

**My idea:**
If we don't shy away from using Dirac deltas, we can do the following. First note that
$$ g(L) = \int\int_\mathbb{R^2} [\theta(x+L)-\theta(x-L)][\theta(y+L)-\theta(y-L)]f(x,y) \mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y, $$
where the Heaviside function $\theta(x)=0$ if $x\leq 0$, and $\theta(x) =1$ else. Now the integration limits don't depend on $L$ anymore, and we may perform the differentiation using that $\theta'(x)=\delta(x)$, where $\delta(x)$ is Dirac's delta distribution. Then, by the product rule,
$$ g'(L) = \int\int_\mathbb{R^2} [\delta(x+L)-\delta(x-L)][\theta(y+L)-\theta(y-L)] + [[\theta(x+L)-\theta(x-L)][\delta(y+L)-\delta(y-L)] \mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y, $$
which may be evaluated as 
$$ g'(L)=\int_{-L}^L f(-L,y)\mathrm{d}y - \int_{-L}^{L} f(L,y)\mathrm{d}y +\int_{-L}^L f(x,-L)\mathrm{d}x - \int_{-L}^{L} f(x,L)\mathrm{d}x.  $$
This result however puzzles me. It doesn't seem to be the line integral along the edges of the square but rather looks as follows

$$---\leftarrow---$$
$$ |   \phantom{tttttttttextttttt}| $$
$$ \uparrow   \phantom{tttttttttextttttt}\downarrow $$
$$ |   \phantom{tttttttttextttttt}| $$
$$---\rightarrow---$$

This however looks weird to me, why would the edges have such strange directions? Did I make a mistake and if not, can you give an intuitive reason for this result?

**EDIT:** I think that something isn't quite right because if I just take $f(x,y)=1$ everywhere (that is not integrable on $\mathbb{R^2}$ but on any finite subset of it). Then $g(L)=4L^2$, hence $g'(L)=8L$, however, our nice formula gives us the wrong answer $g'(L)=0$ for all $L$. Where did things go wrong??

**EDIT 2:** I found a different way of computing the derivative which is much more elementary. It only uses Leibnitz's rule for a single integral and the mean value theorem (for double integrals). However, I wind up with the same wrong answer in the end (!!). This is beginning to be scary.

\begin{align}
g'(L) =& \lim_{\Delta \to 0} \frac{1}{\Delta} \left( \int_{-(L+\Delta)}^{L+\Delta} \int_{-(L+\Delta)}^{L+\Delta} f(x,y)\mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}y - \int_{-L}^{L} \int_{-L}^{L} f(x,y)\mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}y  \right) \\
=& \lim_{\Delta \to 0} \frac{1}{\Delta} \left( \left(\int_{-(L+\Delta)}^{-L} + \int_{-L}^L + \int_{L}^{L+\Delta}\right) \left( \int_{-(L+\Delta)}^{-L} + \int_{-L}^L + \int_{L}^{L+\Delta}\right) f(x,y)\mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}y \\- \int_{-L}^{L} \int_{-L}^{L} f(x,y)\mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}y  \right) \\
=& \lim_{\Delta \to 0} \frac{1}{\Delta} \left( \left(\int_{-(L+\Delta)}^{-L} + \int_{-L}^L + \int_{L}^{L+\Delta}\right) \left( \int_{-(L+\Delta)}^{-L} + \int_{-L}^L + \int_{L}^{L+\Delta}\right) f(x,y)\mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}y \\- \int_{-L}^{L} \int_{-L}^{L} f(x,y)\mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}y  \right) \\
=& \lim_{\Delta \to 0} \frac{1}{\Delta} \left[\left( \underbrace{\int_{-(L+\Delta)}^{-L} \left( \int_{-(L+\Delta)}^{-L}+\int_L^{L+\Delta}\right) +  \int_{L}^{L+\Delta} \left( \int_{-(L+\Delta)}^{-L}+\int_L^{L+\Delta}\right)}_{(*)}  \\ +\int_{-L}^L \left( \int_{-(L+\Delta)}^{-L} +\int_L^{L+\Delta}\right) + \left(\int_{-(L+\Delta)}^{-L} +\int_{L}^{L+\Delta}\right)\int_{-L}^L \right) f(x,y)\mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}y  \right]
\end{align} 
The MVT for double integrals says that for a continuous function $h(x,y)$ integrated over a compact connected subset $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R^2}$ of area $A_\Omega$ satisfies: $\int\int_\Omega h(x,y) = A h(x_o,y_o)$ for some $x_o, y_o$ in $\Omega$. Now, we apply this to the (*) terms which shows that $(*) = O(\Delta^2)$, hence they do not contribute to the derivative. Now carefully evaluating each of the remaining for integrals shows that we get the same weird integral along the edges as before...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $g(L) = F(-L,L,-L,L)$ where $$F(r,s,u,v) = \int_r^s\int_u^v f(x,y)dxdy$$

And $$\frac {dg}{dL} = \frac{\partial F}{\partial r}\frac{dr}{dL} + \frac{\partial F}{\partial s}\frac{ds}{dL} +\frac{\partial F}{\partial u}\frac{du}{dL} + \frac{\partial F}{\partial v}\frac{dv}{dL}$$

Comment: It should be $F(r,s,u,v) = \int_{-r}^s\int_{-u}^v f(x,y) \mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}y$  for $g(L)=F(L,L,L,L)$ to be true.

Comment: @Cyclone - true. I've corrected it, though I chose to change the values of $r, u$ in the expression for $g$ instead.

Comment: This is a very helpful answer, thank you. Now I get that $g'(L)=\int_{L-}^L f(-L,y)dy + \int_{L-}^L f(L,y)dy + \int_{L-}^L f(x,-L)dx + \int_{L-}^L f(x,L)dx$ which gives $g'(L)=8L$ for $f\equiv 1$, so it seems correct. But I was wondering, do you have an idea why both my other attempts failed?

Comment: In the first attempt, $$\frac{d\theta(x-L)}{dL} = -\delta(x-L)$$

Comment: And it appears that your second attempt is correct, but you misinterpreted it

Comment: Sometimes, it's just too obvious...

Comment: It usually is. Such issues are seldom difficult once you see the solution. The problem is in getting past the blinders that keep leading you into the same dead-end.